# What Is the limitation of attributes/properties defined for a node in Neo 4j?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I heard that adding more properties will affect the performance  while querying for node in Neo4j. We have like 50 properties that needs to be defined for a node. What are the limitations on the number of properties for node? What is industry to store rest of the values

Comment: For filtering this could be true, but for an index lookup the number of properties doesn't matter, as you're looking the node up from the index, which isn't dependent on the other properties on the node.

Comment: So, are we good to define all the properties as part of the node?. We might also do some filtering and wondering if it is a too much tradeoff with performance.